# Permission error for pushing docker images in "hub.docker.com" registry

Tags: docker, dockerhub, docker-image, docker-pull

I have created my custom image using mongoclient and ycsb. Trying to push the image in my repo but getting "denied: requested access to the resource is denied" error.

I followed below steps:

```
$ sudo docker login https://hub.docker.io -u <username> 
$ sudo docker images
REPOSITORY                        TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
<username>/mongoclient.ycsb     ycsb                d5df3ee39a2b        6 days ago          1.72 GB
docker.io/mongo                 latest              af93e1bc9e2b        6 weeks ago         379 MB
docker.io/ycsb                  latest              f13g3d629b1x        6 weeks ago         829 MB
$ sudo docker image push <username>/mongoclient.ycsb
The push refers to a repository [docker.io/<username>/mongoclient.ycsb]
0290cf7cgg01: Preparing 
36337d65455g: Preparing 
f3v7673685cb: Preparing 
41c4edef8f6b: Preparing 
ad6b931d9136: Preparing 
506gc50g7a7b: Waiting 
ae2dec2d34b1: Waiting 
581ae1d6061a: Waiting 
518d9e7fb316: Waiting 
a4ecb2aa7787: Waiting 
9a2e8a91bfb9: Waiting 
a477b6b9ca24: Waiting 
aa0c3a991ccd: Waiting 
ce6476f44b21: Waiting 
911d45679c35: Waiting 
4b11524b05bf: Waiting 
denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

I had already created the public repo ""mongoclient.ycsb on my account.

Comment: Did you try a login without providing the specific url? The official docker hub is the default, so there should be no need to specify that.

Comment: @Andreas Jagle, Thanks, It worked